# OpenCV - save Mat in Vector<Mat>

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to save Mat into std::vector and play video after this.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;

    vector<Mat> v;
    Mat m;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        cap >> m;
        v.push_back(m);
    }
    puts("After:\n");

    for (auto i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        imshow("Camera", v[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But there is nothing :) Opens "Camera" window and closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace `v.push_back(m)` with `v.push_back(m.clone())` as you need each vector entry to be a separate matrix, now they all share the same data.
2. Add delay in your loop: before or after `imshow()`
3. Add `waitKey(0)` call before `return 0`;